# Updating a memoized global variable

Tags: python, fibonacci

```
global res

res = dict()

res[0] = 0

res[1] =1


def fib(n):

    if n in res:
        return res[n]
    else: value = fib(n-1) + fib (n-2) 
    res[n] = value
    print res
    return value


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print fib(10)
```

Here I am trying to access res which is declared global from the main prompt, but when I say print res, it only shows me the old dictionary and not any updated values even after calling the fib function. I am running this on windows cmd and when I say old dictionary I mean the res with 0 and 1 as keys.

Comment: You only need to declare a variable as `global` if you're going to assign to it in a function.  Modifying it (by subscripting it) is perfectly fine.

Comment: This works fine for me (the last line printed is `{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 5, 6: 8, 7: 13, 8: 21, 9: 34, 10: 55}`).  What output do you get?

Comment: As @ecatmur says, you do not need the ``global res`` statement, it can be removed (it does not make sense to use ``global`` outside a function). And I can confirm that it works as expected for me as well.